# Sharp subsurf corners on a curved plane?

Tags: subdivision-surface

I am having trouble closing up this surface. Rings don't appear to be applicable and creases only get rid of the smoothing.

[image]

Comment: The edge which goes from the corner to the center should be creased as well.

Comment: attach the file http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ here to get detail answer